# How would I extract this with Python regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull the date time out from:

```
<time datetime="2015-07-25T10:06:46-0700">2015-07-25 10:06am</time>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4237058)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/4698093)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup` parser.

```
>>> html = '''<time datetime="2015-07-25T10:06:46-0700">2015-07-25 10:06am</time>'''
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.findAll('time')[0].text
'2015-07-25 10:06am'
```

With `re`,

```
re.search(r'<time\b[^>]*>([^<>]*)</time>', s).group(1)
```

Comment: I know how to do it with BeautifulSoup, I'm trying to do it with re.